error reading .LAS file with pylas.lasmmap.lasMMAP()
When I try to use the pylas.lasmmap module in python: https://pylas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pylas.lasmmap.html
to read a .lasfile i get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Division Nät\Anläggningar\NAG\VERKSAMHET\Verktyg\Python\Hantera laserdata\test.py", line 35, in <module>
    las = pylas.lasmmap.LasMMAP(strLAS)
  File "C:\Users\repa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pylas\lasmmap.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.points_data = record.PackedPointRecord.from_buffer(
  File "C:\Users\repa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pylas\point\record.py", line 282, in from_buffer
    points_dtype = point_format.dtype
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dtype'
PS G:\Division Nät\Anläggningar\NAG\VERKSAMHET\Verktyg\Python\Hantera laserdata> 

Here's my code:
#import package

import pylas.lasmmap

#set path
path = r'C:/mypath/lasfile.las'

#read las
las = pylas.lasmmap.lasMMAP(path)

I've tried to read the .lasfile with "pylas.read", but get a memoryerror.

Alternative solution:
read the lasfiles with laspy instead of pylas which doesnt create a memoryerror.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
